# Python Azure Apps 404 in paths

Tags: python, azure, flask

I followed this [Create a Python app in Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python) and uploaded my code with the folowing functions:

```
@app.route('/predict_json', methods=['POST'])
def add_message():
    content = request.json

    tweets = pd.DataFrame(content)
    tweets["polarity"] = pipeline.predict(tweets.Tweet)   

    return tweets.to_json()

@app.route('/predict')
def predict():
    # Retrieve query parameters related to this request.
    content = request.args.get('content')    

    d = {'tweet': [content]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    # Use the model to predict the class
    label_index = pipeline.predict(df.tweet)
    # Retrieve the iris name that is associated with the predicted class
    label = MODEL_LABELS[label_index[0]]
    label_int = MODEL_INT[label_index[0]]
    # Create and send a response to the API caller
    return jsonify(status='complete',tweet=content, polarity=label_int, polarity_text=label)
```

In local they work perfect. But when deployed I got 404.

My code is here [https://github.com/mulflar/saturdayAi/blob/master/twitteranalisisdesentimientosnlp.py](https://github.com/mulflar/saturdayAi)

Comment: Which route is giving you 404, can you post the error too?

Comment: both of them the full path is https://tweetsaturday.azurewebsites.net/predict and https://tweetsaturday.azurewebsites.net/predict_json

Answer (score 0):

Can you try either

- renaming `twitteranalisisdesentimientosnlp.py` to `app.py`

OR

- Since your main application file is not called app.py or application.py, then you need to specify what command to run at startup (see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python#customize-startup-command) for more info). In this case it would be:

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 twitteranalisisdesentimientosnlp:app #The :app corresponds to the name of the flask app inside of the file
```

Comment: I ran your code in an App Service of my own last night and I noticed that the app was not starting in a timely manner. I think that this is because it is attempting to do all of your app logic upon startup. It might be an idea to wrap the logic inside of a function and then call that as part a new `/startup` route. Alternatively place the logic into a function and then add the `@app.before_first_request` decorator to it so that it runs whenever the flask app receives its first request.

Comment: I don't know the libraries you are using that well, but typically your long running jobs i.e. `/predict` and `/predict_json` would place a result into a database that you would then read from using another route e.g. `/view_predictions`